# Rails6 : Multiple applications with NGINX passenger not serving POST requests from sub-URIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, passenger-nginx

I want to run two Rails6 applications on the same server at two sub-URIs using NGINX and Passenger. The root is a static index.html.

The index page loads correctly from the root. So do the root views of the Rails applications when the sub-URIs are accessed. However, subsequent form submits throw 404.

Both the applications run fine when I run them on root (/) instead of the static index page.

Configuration file is sites-enabled folder has --

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name _;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
        passenger_app_env development;

        location / {
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ ^/rbf(/.*|$) {
                alias /var/www/rails6-bootstrap-flatpickr/public$1;
                passenger_base_uri /rbf;
                passenger_app_root /var/www/rails6-bootstrap-flatpickr;
                passenger_document_root /var/www/rails6-bootstrap-flatpickr/public;
        }

        location ~ ^/cdb(/.*|$) {
                alias /var/www/dashboard/public$1;
                passenger_base_uri /cdb;
                passenger_app_root /var/www/dashboard;
                passenger_document_root /var/www/dashboard/public;
        }
        
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

The NGINX access log has the following line (I have replaced my ip address with aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd)

```
[19/Nov/2020:12:00:59 +0000] "POST /display_router HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/cdb" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In development I had each app running on its own Rails server.
The form definitions were:

```
<%= form_with(url: "/process_dates") do %>
```

and

```
<%= form_with(url: "/display_router") do %>
```

The forms were being posted to root folder /process_dates and /display_router respectively.
But on the cloud server, each application is in its own folder which is the rails root.

So I just changed the form definitions on the cloud server to

```
<%= form_with(url: "/rbf/process_dates") do %>
```

and

```
<%= form_with(url: "/cdb/display_router") do %>
```

and it worked.